# Error occurred when running pip install mysql-python: "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, mysql-python

Running `pip install mysql-python` gives "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 issue

Tried `pip install -U setuptools` to update the setuptools to the latest version, which gets 'Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages'.

Also tried `python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools` which should be the same function as above.

Also tried to run `brew install mysql-connector-c` and then run `pip install mysql-python`, but still not working.

ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_0/9_462vd15jgg2s365ldbgt440000gn/T/pip-install-_gamvb3n/mysql-python/

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can install `mysql-python` with pip...

Try to download the connector from here and install it: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

> You may also need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 (but I'm not 100% sure of that)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and will try, but the pip way installation should be fine as it is also suggested by pypi, which can refer to https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/

Comment: The [github repo](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1) of the pypi package has not been updated for 6 years, though...

Comment: In my opinion, this answer should have been accepted. The recommended dev download worked for me (without additional Visual downloads required), while pip did not.